# User agent blacklist recommended

Tags: blacklist, useragent

Perishable Press publishes a managed user agent blacklist frequently, which blocks bad bots which htaccess directives.

Article to be found here: http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/03/29/4g-ultimate-user-agent-blacklist/

Would you recommend using such a blacklist? The main goal is to reduce request on my servers, because I see a lot of traffic is consumed by bots visiting my site.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally yes if it meets your requirements/needs, unless there are specific conflicts you can find with their definitions and/or approaches. The prudent route is to monitor very closely during its initial implementation to ensure it fits your needs without introducing any unanticipated/unexpected side-affects.

Answer (score 4):

You're better off using `robots.txt` to control the well-behaved bots, and request rate-limiting for evil bots.  You can't use anything controlled by the client for badly-behaved bots, because they can modify themselves to evade your filters.